# Какая буква пишется в слове ведший: ё или е?

Tags: этимология

*гнев, ведший людей к победе на войне*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ведший пишется через **е**, но если копнуть чуть глубже, то всё не так просто.

Действительно есть сложные правила, которые применимы к похожим словам. А. Зализняк в своём "Грамматическом словаре" говорит следующее:

> **Действительное причастие прошедшего времени**
> Имеется у глаголов обоих видов. Образуется от формы прош. м: если эта форма оканчивается
> на **-л** — заменой **-л** на **-вший**, если она оканчивается иначе —
> добавлением к ней **-ший**. Ударение такое же, как в прош. м.
> **Исключения:** 1) у глаголов на **-сти** типа 7 с пометой (-т-) или (-д-) это причастие образуется добавлением **-ший** к основе 1 ед.
> наст, (буд.) (мести, мету — мётший), ударение (и выбор е или ё), как в
> прош. м; 2) ...

Вот под исключение 1 попадает кроме **мести** ещё **плести** и **гнести** (и другие с этими же корнями тоже, конечно). Почему под это правило не попадают **вести** и **цвести**, я не могу сказать уверенно, но выглядит так, что это исключения из исключений. Про них уже в самих словарных статьях отдельно говорится примерно так (для **вести**): парадигма на ё, "но прич. прош. **ведший**". В некоторых старых словарях ещё было **расцвётший**.

Comment: *не попадают вести и цвести, я не могу сказать уверенно* - да ну что вы. "цвести" писался через ять, тут именно что переход в Ё исключение.   Вот параллель мести-вести - это да, интереснее. Надо полагать, Ё во втором случае (вёл) вторично, то есть появилось по какой-то аналогии с тем же "мёл". Иначе объяснить трудно, его нет ни в одной форме, кроме этого самого "вёл" ...

Answer (score 1):

Конечно Е.
В любом словаре проверяется.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9&all=x-

Интересно другое, с чего вы решили, что там может быть Ё?
Причин для того нет никаких. Даже аналогии с каким-то вариантом не вижу, как ни кручу...

*Есть даже предположение, что Ё вообще не бывает перед сочетанием типа ТШ, ДШ, ДЖ. Но тут я могу ошибаться...*

Comment: Просто в слове вёл меняется

Comment: И в интернете часто в принципе встречается

Comment: @Лев - гризли привел параллель (ложную) с мести, так что я снимаю этот вопрос.  А что до интернета - нут так там еще и не то можно найти.